# error acceder a HUE a traves de cloudera

Tags: docker

necesito acceder al puerto 8888 de hue el cual deberia ser con 127.0.0.1:8888 pero me da error de conexion, agregue al archivos hosts 127.0.0.1 quickstart.cloudera, estoy utilizando docker toolbox a trves de una vm virtualbox. el servicio de hue se supone esta corriendo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si intento acceder con la ip que aparece en kitematic el error es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo resolví agregando el `127.0.0.1 quickstart.cloudera` dentro del contenedor que utilizo `cdh_c1` , y luego usando en el navegador la ip de la maquina , no `127.0.0.1`